# Prefill new user registration fields in the backend by URL

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, com-users

Hey I want to prefill in `new user` details by setting the parameters in a link.

I am talking about the default Joomla User Manager in the BACKEND and then clicked on new user.

So this link,

```
administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=user&layout=edit&id=0&jform_username=test
```

would already prefill in the username field with the word `test`.

I tried numerous suggestions from the web to make this work but sadly no luck. I also tried with different fields and switching between the name of the field and the ID `jform[username] or jform_username`.

Comment: Generally speaking, `$_GET` parameters (data visible in the url's query string) are to be used when performing READ-type operations on the server-side.  When performing CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE operations, it is best practice to pass data via `$_POST`. One reason for this is that if a bot/hacker becomes aware of your links, they can mangle your users table in mere seconds via automated pageloading scripts.  Whether or not this is a credible scenario for your project is not my point.  It is a professional practice to split submitted data to CRUD operations in the way that I have described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, Joomla! uses a CSRF Token to secure any sensitive information in order to attempt to prevent any malicious form manipulation.
The short answer you need the token to attempt to do this via url but it might not work.
Your best bet would be to use your favorite web browser autofill capabilities.
Take care.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I am going to look into this CSRF Token and see if it works.

Comment: Indeed Joomla! uses the CSRF Token and I did look briefly into it but decided to go with another way for creating the Joomla User in my extension. I do however like to keep the question open as there might be someone who can give an example with the CSRF Token included. This for future reference for all Joomla! users.